# End points interval of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

I am trying to evaluate the end points of an interval of convergence of the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((n+1)x)^n}{n^{n+1}}$$
Applying root test:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(n+1)x)^n}{n^{n+1}}\right|}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)x}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\right|=\left|x\right|$$
But when I plug in $x=1$ we will get the same as above and root test will return $1$ again, which isn't much help so I was wandering if I went wrong somewhere or if there is a better way to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $n\to\infty$, $\displaystyle \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}} \approx \frac e n $ so your series  should have end point of convergence like of  $ \displaystyle \sum \frac{x^n}{n}$.
In your attempt of solution, if
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)x}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\right| < 1$$
then the series converges absolutely and 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n^{1 + \frac 1 n}} = 1$$
that will give you $|x| < 1$

Comment: Oops.  Deleted my comment right before you edited, because I realized that your solution was still perfectly fine, and my comment only slightly refined the answer you gave.

Comment: @NicholasStull I had to recheck my answer by seeing your comment to avoid downvotes. Thanks ... I should have mentioned your comment on answer.

Answer (score 2):

From
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}=e$$
we have that $$\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n}}=\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n=O\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right),\;\;n\to\infty.$$